# Redirecting the output of ps command,getting process id and killing that process using shell script

Tags: shell

I want to write a shell script to find the running process for a given user and kill the process by getting the respective process ID.

Its like

```
ps -ef | grep dinesh
```

After this, i am getting the output as the following

```
dinesh 19985 19890  0 11:35 pts/552  00:00:00 grep dinesh
```

Here 19985 is the process ID. I want to kill that process.

How can i achieve this using script?

I have to parse the ps command output and get the process ID

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
kill `ps -ef | grep dinesh | awk '{ print $2 }'`
```

Comment: Thank you so much nab. :). Its much useful.

Comment: It works also with ps aux _kill `ps aux | grep dinesh | awk '{ print $2 }'`_

Answer (score 5):

What if there is more than one process defined by the string `'dinesh'`?  What about the grep process itself?  This is a more complete answer

`ps -ef | grep dinesh | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9`

Comment: short: `ps -ef | awk '/d[i]nesh/{print $2}'` that square bracket is a neat trick to avoid awk process itself from ps output